# Why and in which cases spring load bean twice using different classLoaders?

Tags: java, spring, classloader, classcastexception

Recently I visited an interview.

I was asked:

```
MyClass myClass =(MyClass) applicationContext.getBean("myClass");
```

throws `ClassCastException`

but `applicationContext.getBean("myClass").getClass()` returns `MyClass`.

I was surprised about the question. I could reply only that classes loaded by different classloaders.

1. How to achieve this ?
2. Why Spring uses different classloaders ?

Comment: Are both `MyClass` the same class from the same package ?

Comment: @Berger yes, sure

Answer (score 1):

Yes different classloader will lead to this scenario. This is not that common scenario however some application uses multiple classloaders (most common examples are containers and application servers). You can reproduce it

You can initialize spring application context by specifying `URLClassLoader`

Have your class located at

```
/home/jigar.joshi/foo/package/MyClass
```

and configure application context to use URLClassLoader like this

```
URL[] classURLs = { new URL("file:///home/jigar.joshi/foo") };
URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(classURLs);
ApplicationContext context = new     ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring/applicationContext.xml") {
            protected void initBeanDefinitionReader(XmlBeanDefinitionReader reader) {
                super.initBeanDefinitionReader(reader);
                reader.setValidationMode(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.VALIDATION_NONE);
                reader.setBeanClassLoader(urlClassLoader);
                setClassLoader(urlClassLoader);
            }
        };

        MyClass m = context.getBean("MyClass");
```

Comment: what the possible reason to have this functionality ?

Comment: I worked only with Tomcat/jetty. Please, provide example for these containers.

Comment: when tomcat has to multiple application. it is possible that multiple application has same class name. it uses different classloaders for each application that way

Comment: but looks like different applications isolated apart

Comment: Yes they are isolated on same JVM when you launch tomcat to deploy 2 war

Comment: at this case I don't see the possibility to get ClasscastException

Comment: I was just mentioning one of the use case where you want multiple classloaders. possibility of classcast exception can arise if your app has multiple classloaders and it tries to cast simply

Comment: Why can I want to have different classloaders for different contexts ?