# A synchronized method call in Java is ignoring an initialization Flag (spring)

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc, classloader

Sorry for the bad title, but the explanation will be very simple.

I have, on a Service on Spring this method:

```
private static boolean initialized = false;

@PostConstruct
public void onPostConstruct() {
   synchronized (MyClass.class) {
        if (!initialized) {
            // do some init 
            startThread();
            initialized = true
        }
   }
}
```

JavaSE-wise, I'm 100% confident that there can't be more than one thread started by the call startThread(). It has something to do with the loading of classes in Spring, because there's more than one thread. I see it in the logs.

I cannot reproduce the bug on my computer, only on the server, and I don't have access, so, I ask here. If someone can float me some light! thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding volatile keyword with initialized  variable declaration ? I think you are having more than one bean declarations for this class that is why constructor (and this method) is being called simultaneously.  Also this doesn't seem correct way to start a thread (if you only want one thread). You should see if you can use Singleton class. Add more details if issue is not solved.

Comment: @Amit: `volatile` should not be necessary here as the `synchronized` guarantees happens-before ordering. Volatile would only be necessary in the absence of proper synchronization.

Comment: Does startThread() execute code that may again call onPostConstruct()?

Comment: @rmunge no, not at all.

Answer (score 2):

**Your code is definitely thread safe**. Multiple calls to startThread() will only possible be if your class is loaded more than ones by different ClassLoaders.

I'm not a Spring expert but according to the answers of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41714678/why-and-in-which-cases-spring-load-bean-twice-using-different-classloaders) question it is possible to specify a `ClassLoader` for each ApplicationContext. If your class should be used in multiple ApplicationContexts with different ClassLoader instances it would be possible, that there exist two class objects for your class. Since you synchronize by the class object, calls to onPostConstruct() would only be mutually exclusive for one instance of the class.

To verify that your code is called for multiple instances of the class, extend your code with some logging and log the return value of MyClass.class.getClassLoader().

Answer (score -1):

During execution, static variable value are initialised to class but not instance, so if you have a any one instant of your Service changed the initialized to true, then it changed to true forever for all instance.

for @PostConstruct, it will be called when the constructor is called, and for Spring server, all the class will be constructed as bean during startup, so this method should be called once, so before the start of service, the flag already changed to true.

I suggest you to create an other method to change the flag rather than in post construct.

Comment: 1) yeah, that's what I want. I want everything in the PostConstruct to execute only once, that's why I made it like that. 2) the second part I did not understand.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the issue with the order of execution between startThread() method and the reassignment of initialized variable.

First Execution: startThread() method, is it starting a thread ??

at the same time initialized reassigned to true;